# Мурал чи стінопис?

Tags: вживання-слів

Текст із завдання ЗНО

> За кілька останніх років митці прикрасили зовнішні стіни київських
>   будівель десятками яскравих і масштабних малюнків – муралів.
>   Талановиті художники з України, Іспанії, Аргентини, Австралії та
>   Франції оживили урбаністичний пейзаж столиці захопливими
>   картинами. Мурали – один із різновидів сучасного вуличного живопису.

***Мурал*** — художній розпис зовнішніх стін будинків у міському просторі.

Чи нормативним є вживання слова ***мурал***, в словниках слово відсутнє. Можливо пізніше буде в СУМ-20.

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/mural) пропонує заміну *стінопис, розпис*.

В СУМ-11 присутнє визначення [стінопис](http://sum.in.ua/s/stinopys).

Вікіпедії стаття

> [**Стінопис** або **мурал**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) — різновид монументального і
>   декоративного малярства, що виконувалося безпосередньо на стіні або на
>   штукатурці, закріпленій на стіні, в якому фігуративні образи й
>   декоративні орнаменти підпорядковуються архітектурним формам.

Answer (score 1):

Так, справді, це слово тільки починає входити в "активну" лексику. Проф. О. Пономанів у своєму [блозі](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2016/04/160418_ponomariv_blog86_ko) пише:

> **Стінопис** утворено за зразком живопис, літопис, рукопис тощо. Отже це цілком українське слово.
>
> Мур – синонім до слова стіна, давнє запозичення з німецької мови, має велике словотвірне гніздо: мурувати, мурування, мурований , підмурівок та инші. **Мурал** поки що словники української мови не фіксують.

Однак роблю гіпотезу, що професор скоріш за все має на увазі академічні видання, адже це слово знаходимо й у Вами наведеній [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB&redirect=no), й у [Словнику іншомовних слів](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Qry=%CC%F3%F0%E0%EB):

> **Мурал** - 1. Декоративний розпис стіни або стелі з гармонійним включенням в композицію архітектурних елементів робочої поверхні; стінопис. 2. Твір, виконаний у подібній техніці.

Отже, оскільки лексика української мови є відкритою системою, що завжди поповнюється, то на даний час слово "**мурал**" - це лише запозичення, як безліч інших слів, які ми використовуємо, що не є фіксовані словниками. Таким чином воно вживається радше в розмовному стилі. Однак є всі шанси, що це слово стане фіксованим на рівні академічних видань.